# Rails: js.erb doesn't get executed on client?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have problem getting the respond script to run on the client. I am quite new to rails, and I am not sure what the remote: true does.  I have the following link:

```
<%= link_to "#{p.title}", post_path(p), remote: true %>
```

when I click on it, it directs to the show action which renders post content, and I want to parse the content to a div. My show.js.erb looks like this

```
$("#content").html("<h2><%= @post.title %> </h2><p><%= @post.body %></p>");
```

when I click on the link, I get this responds.

```
Started GET "/posts/14" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-28 10:51:12 -0800
Processing by PostsController#show as JS
Parameters: {"id"=>"14"}
Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "14"]]
Rendered posts/show.js.erb (0.2ms)
```

I do get the whole jquery code looking at the http respond, but somehow it doesn't get executed.

Comment: Is there a tag with the id `content` on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`escape_javascript`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) in `show.js.erb` as:

```
$("#content").html("<h2><%= escape_javascript @post.title %> </h2><p><%= escape_javascript @post.body %></p>");
```

A cleaner and DRY approach for this would be to move the following:

```
<h2><%= @post.title %> </h2><p><%= @post.body %></p>`
```

to a partial and render that partial in `show.js.erb`.

```
# _post_detail.html.erb
<h2><%= @post.title %> </h2><p><%= @post.body %></p>
```

Then in `show.js.erb`:

```
$('#content').html(<%= escape_javascript render("post_detail") %>);
```